# Image in header won't show

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to build an interface that has a header bar with a logo centered in the top. Here's the code I'm using. The image doesn't show. Upon inspecting the elements at run time, element is showing with a height of '0' instead of using the 100% to match the height of the containing element.

```
Ext.define("RFN.view.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',

    config: {
         tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
         items: [
            {
             title: 'Calculate',
             iconCls: 'home',
             //styleHtmlContent: true,
             //scrollable: true,
             layout: 'vbox',
             items:[
               {
                xtype: 'panel',
                style: 'background-color: #174a7c;text-align:center;',
                items:[
                  {
                   xtype: 'image',
                   src: 'resources/images/logo.png',
                   height: '100%'
                  }
                ],
                flex: 1
              },
              {
               xtype: 'panel',
               style: 'background-color: #999999;',
               flex:4
              }
             ]
            },
            {
             title: 'Compare',
             iconCls: 'chart2',
             //styleHtmlContent: true,
             //scrollable: true,
             layout: 'vbox',
             items:[
               {
                style: 'background-color: #174a7c;',
                flex: 1
               },
               {
                style: 'background-color: #999999;',
                flex:4
               }
             ]
            }
         ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a layout config on the panel that contains the image. You can then remove the height config on you image as the layout make the inner item fit the whole height and width automatically :

```
...
xtype: 'panel',
style: 'background-color: #174a7c;text-align:center;',
items:[{
    xtype: 'image',
    src: 'resources/images/logo.png',
}],
flex: 1
...
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do what I did and have a layout of vbox, the header had a flex of 0.3 and my tabpanel 0.7. The item that was 0.3 was a panel, and in the class config (cls) I had my CSS class name e.g. Header. In my CSS class .header I had set the background and logo. Hope this helps...